# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired en dockerfile

Tags: docker, yarn

Estimados tengo este problema corriendo un comando curl apuntando a yarn descargando uno paquetes de yarn les dejo un print del error y el dockerfile

lo estoy intentando ejecutar desde un ubuntu 20.04

```
#FROM keymetrics/pm2:8 FROM node:12.14.0-alpine

RUN apk update \   && apk add curl \   && apk add make \   && apk add gcc \   && apk add g++ \   && apk add git \   && apk add openssh \   && apk add python \   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV YARN_VERSION=1.17.3 RUN cd /opt \   && rm -fr /opt/yarn* \   && curl -L -O https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/${YARN_VERSION}/yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}.tar.gz \   && ls -alh /opt \   && tar zvxf yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}.tar.gz \   && rm yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}.tar.gz \   && rm /usr/local/bin/yarn \   && rm /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \   && ln -s /opt/yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \   && ln -s /opt/yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg

WORKDIR /app
```

y el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error es que el server (en este caso el alpine del docker con el node:12.14.0-alpine) no puede establecer la confianza en el certificado provisto por https://yarnpkg.com, el problema se solucionaría actualizando los certificados ca antes de hacer el `curl`.

La forma mas fácil de solucionarlo es intentar con otra versión de node/alpine, por ejemplo la `node:12.22-alpine` que es la mas cercana a node:12.14.0-alpine en dockerhub.

Si fuese necesario mantener la versión del node/alpine hay que [actualizar los cerfificados ca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).